# Create a CSV from Text File useing Linux Console

Tags: regex, linux, bash, csv

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
    line1
    line2
    line3
    line4
    line5
    "" "" keep going for a long time
```

I'm trying to come up with a script that would give me:

```
    line1,line2,line3,line4,line5
    line6,line7,line8,line9,line10
```

So comma separate them all and add a newline every 5.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have perl, try this:

```
perl -ane '++$i; chomp; $line.=$_; if($i==5) {print "$line\n"; $line=""; $i=0;} else {$line.=","} ' <infile >outfile
```

Answer (score 4):

```
paste -d, - - - - - < filename
```

[man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste)

Comment: Nice, I had not heard of paste before!  I also like that given an input that's not an even multiple of 5, there are still empty fields with delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

A bit rough but workable w/out resorting to the, perhaps more pleasing, perl solution. The -n 5 arg to xargs makes it just send 5 arguments to the shell script, which we print.

```
$ cat echo.sh 
echo $1,$2,$3,$4,$5
$ $ cat file.txt 
a
b
c
d
e
1
2
3
4
5
$ cat file  | xargs -n 5 ./echo.sh
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5
$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat foo.txt | xargs -L 5 | tr ' ' ','
```

The plus side here is that you can also modify the '5' arguments to an arbitrary value and the  script works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Python is installed by default on every linux distro these days.

I'd suggest the following python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse, csv
if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='convert text to csv', version='%(prog)s 1.0')
    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='+', type=str, help='list of input files')
    parser.add_argument('--out', type=str, default='temp.csv', help='name of output file')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    writer = csv.DictWriter(open(args.out, "wb"), ["field 1","field 2","field 3","field 4","field 5"], dialect='excel')
    # write the header at the top of the file
    writer.writeheader()
    row = []

    for fname in args.infile:
        with open(fname) as df:
            for line in df.readlines():
                row.append(line.strip('\n'))
                if len(row) = 5:
                    writer.writerow(row)
                    row = []
    del writer
```

You should be able to copy the code into a file and run it right off the command line. For instance: `text2csv.py yourinput.txt` if, of course, you called the file `text2csv.py`.